# TypeError: Font.isLoaded is not a function. @expo/vector-icons

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-application

I got this error when I used @expo/vector-icons. How do I solve this problem?

[image: error]

I've tried to run npm install and upgrade the expo, but still got the error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { ListItem, Separator } from '../components/List';

const ICON_COLOR = '#868686';
const ICON_SIZE = 23;

class Options extends Component {
  handlePressThemes = () => {
   console.log('press themes');
};

handlePressSite = () => {
   console.log('press site');
};

render() {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
    <StatusBar translucent={false} barStyle="default" />
    <ListItem
      text="Themes"
      onPress={this.handlePressThemes}
      customIcon={<Ionicons name="arrow-right" size={ICON_SIZE} color={ICON_COLOR} />}
    />
    <Separator />
    <ListItem
      text="Fixer.io"
      onPress={this.handlePressSite}
      customIcon={<Ionicons name="link" size={ICON_SIZE} color={ICON_COLOR} />}
    />
    <Separator />
  </ScrollView>
);
}
}
export default Options;
```

Comment: Which version of Expo are you using?

Comment: I'm using 31.0.4 version

Comment: Can I see 'ListItem' screen?

Comment: try downgrading @expo/vector-icons to 8.1.0, If i'm not wrong it's a missmatch between expo version an @expo/vector-icons version, you can do that using npm install @expo/vector-icons@8.1.0

Comment: I've run 'npm update expo' and 'npm install' and it works now